# Is xml document with undeclared prefix well-formed?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, well-formed

For example I have following document:

```
<root>
    <prefix:element>

    </prefix:element>
</root>
```

As you can see, namespace with `prefix` name undeclared. Is this document is not well-formed?

From [w3fools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp) documentation:

> A "Well Formed" XML document has correct XML syntax. The syntax rules:
>
> - XML documents must have a root element
> - XML elements must have a closing tag
> - XML tags are case sensitive
> - XML elements must be properly nested
> - XML attribute values must be quoted

...nothing about namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Namespaces in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) is a separate spec from XML 1.0 itself. The example document you give is well-formed XML 1.0 but is not *namespace-well-formed* according to the namespaces spec, and if you wanted to parse it you'd have to use a parser configured not to be namespace aware.

Comment: Nearly all XML applications these days require namespace-well-formedness.

Comment: @MichaelKay absolutely.  Unfortunately there are also a large number of text-with-angle-brackets applications (as opposed to _XML_ applications) out there, not all of which are responsive to requests to fix their broken XML...

Comment: Sure. There are a lot of ignorant people who are told that users want data in XML and think anything with angle brackets in will meet the requirement. Shun them as you would shun vendors of rotten apples.